# PHP filter_var_array() only check if one value is true?

Tags: php, email, filter, filter-var

I'm trying to check if many e-mail addresses are correct in order to send them.

The thing is, while I filter with `filter_var_array()` and `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`, if only one is correct among all the mails, it still proceeds.

Here is my code:

```
$test_email_friend = explode(",", $email_friend);
if ( !filter_var_array($test_email_friend, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errenvoi = "Please send only valid emails.";
} 
else {  
    //message, headers etc here
    if (mail($email_friend,$sujet,$message,$entete)){               
            $errenvoi = "Email sent !";
    } 
    else {
        $errenvoi = "Something very wrong happened, abandonship, I reapeat abandonship";            
    } 
}
```

For example: If the array contain "test@test.com" and "unvalidmess".
It's sent anyway, because one of the value is correct.

How can I fix this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [the docs](http://php.net/filter_var_array), it says this function only returns `false` on failure (the function failed to execute). Otherwise, it returns an array. So the following for example:

```
$test = array('test@test.com', 'unvalidness');
var_dump(filter_var_array($test, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```

Will output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "test@test.com"
  [1]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

You can alter your code to work by both checking for failure, and searching the returned array for any boolean `false` values:

```
$result = filter_var_array($test, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$result || in_array(false, $result, true)) {
    echo 'failed or data not valid';
}
```

Comment: How did I not think of that ! Sorry, I misread the manual ! Your solution works like a charm ! Thanks a lot !